# Extract properties of a hadoop job

Tags: hadoop

Given a large datafile and jarfile containing mapper, reducer classes , I want to be able to know , how big Hadoop cluster should be formed ( I mean how many machines I would need to form a cluster for the given job to run efficiently.)
I am running the job on the given datafile(s).

Comment: What do you mean by "run efficiently"?

Comment: "run efficiently" meant that, I should get output in less time and I should not end up using extra machines when same can be done in less number of machines.(I have an upper bound on the number of machines available).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming your MapReduce job scales linearly*, I suggest the following test to get a general idea of what you'll need. I assume you have a time in mind when you say "run efficiently"... this might be 1 minute for someone or 1 hour for someone... it's up to you.

Run the job on one node on a subset of your data that fits on one node... or a small number of nodes more preferably. This test cluster should be representative of the type of hardware you will purchase later.

```
  [(time job took on your test cluster) x (number of nodes in test cluster)]
x [(size of full data set) / (size of sample data set)]
/ (new time, i.e., "run efficiently")

= (number of nodes in final cluster)
```

Some things to note:

- If you double the "time job took on test cluster",  you'll need twice as many nodes.
- If you halve the "new time", i.e., you want your job to run twice as fast, you'll need twice as many nodes.
- The ratio of the sample tells you how much to scale the result

---

An example:

I have a job that takes 30 minutes on a two nodes. I am running this job over 4GB of a 400GB data set (400/4 GB). I would like it if my job took 12 minutes.

```
(30 minutes x 2 nodes) x (400 / 4) GB / 12 = 500 nodes
```

---

This is imperfect in a number of ways:

- With one or two nodes, I'm not fully taking into account how long it'll take to transfer stuff over the network... a major part of the mapreduce job. So, you can assume it'll take longer than this estimate. If you can, test your job over 4-10 nodes and scale it from there.
- Hadoop doesn't "scale down" well. There is a certain speed limit that you won't be able to cross with MapReduce. Somewhere around 2-3 minutes on most clusters I've seen. That is, you won't be making a MapReduce job run in 3 seconds by having a million nodes.
- Your job might not scale linearly, in which case this exercise is flawed.
- Maybe you can't find representative hardware. In which case, you'll have to factor in how much faster you think your new system will be.

---

In summary, there is no super accurate way of doing what you say. The best you can really do right now is experimentation and extrapolation. The more nodes you can do a test on, the better, as the extrapolation part will be more accurate.

In my experience, when testing from something like 200 nodes to 800 nodes, this metric is pretty accurate. I'd be nervous about going from 1 node or 2 nodes to 800. But 20 nodes to 800 might be OK.